# How do we use ng-bootstrap for mixins, variables

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have installed @ng-bootstrap, now I want to use mixins inside my **app.component.scss** but getting error

```
Failed to compile.
./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.
      in C:\Users\xxxx\tutorial\xxxx\src\app\app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

following is my app.component.scss

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';
.header_static{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing directly from node_modules folder

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/fucntions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_brekapoints";
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a misunderstanding from my side. I thought when installing ng-bootstrap, it will bring required bootstrap, but it will not.

Totally missed this `Here is a list of minimal required versions of Angular and Bootstrap CSS for ng-bootstrap:` from [Bootstrap widgets - Introduction](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) Then do following imports on your src/styles.scss

```css
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
```